# Magento admin panel: Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules (Percentage off whole cart) Using coupon code

Tags: price, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I'm running 1.14 and you'd think by now they would have developed something for this percentage off the whole cart.

There is "fixed amount discount for whole cart".

Am i missing something or is there really no option for "percent of whole cart price discount".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a **Percent of product price discount** which in your case would be set up for any item in cart.

Set the rule like this: **Discount amount** is percentage value - in this example it's 10%.

In my example there are conditions which are empty in this moment you don't have to have any. Note that I'm blocking any other coupons / promotions from applying by setting field **Stop Further Rules Processing to Yes.**

[image]

Comment: It is a lot different than apply a discount to the total in the cart. It is very weird that Magento don't have this option...

Answer (score 1):

I struggled over this as well, and I found a solution (though not very intuitive).  Simply put a very high number (e.g., 9999) in `Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To` field.  Doing this will cause the single-item rule to apply to each item in the cart, until it reaches the max (9999).  This will work even if you set `Stop Further Rules Processing` to yes.

This is the best workaround I can think of.  It's utterly baffling that a powerful eCommerce solution like Magento has left out such a glaringly obvious coupon scenario that just about every store requires.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I have to switch off "Stop further rules processing" to get the discount to apply to the whole cart, no matter what I put in the "Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" box.